# Getting the sum of a datediff result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL statement (MS SQL Server 2005) that does a simple calculation of the differences in dates on a few records. I want to return the total/sum of the DATEDIFFs too.

```
SELECT     (DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate)+1) AS myTotal
FROM         myTable
WHERE     (Reason = '77000005471247')
```

How do I get the SUM from myTotal? That is all I want to return.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you include any other columns, you'll need to also include a GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT     AnotherColumn, SUM(DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate)+1) AS myTotal
FROM         myTable
WHERE      (Reason = '77000005471247')
GROUP BY   AnotherColumn
```

Comment: Thanks for that, possibly might need that!

Comment: This will give separate sums for each value in `AnotherColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SUM` aggregate:

```
SELECT     SUM(DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate)+1) AS myTotal
FROM         myTable
WHERE     (Reason = '77000005471247')
```