# ACCESS: Get total time different and amount of time ranges above a set amount

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, datediff

I have a table that I'm trying to not only get the sum of time(hours) difference between two columns but also the amount of times a time difference is above a set amount, 6 in this case.

The total I got from [Getting the sum of a datediff result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508338/getting-the-sum-of-a-datediff-result) but can I in the same query also get count(*) where datediff => 6?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: That other question is related to SQL Server, which is quite different from Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateDiff used for hours will probably not be useful, as it will return 1 hour from, say 10:55 to 11:03.

So count minutes:

```
Select
    *, DateDiff("n", [TimeStart], [TimeEnd]) / 60 As Hours
From 
    YourTable
```

Save this query and use it as source in a new query to count those entries with an hour count greater than or equal to six:

```
Select Count(*) As Entries
From YourQuery
Where Hours >= 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the hours. This seems to work. Thanks mate.

Comment: What do you mean save the query? I was under the impression you can't use saved queries unless they are action.

Comment: Then you have been misguided. Any query can be saved.