# Query who looks if employee has more than 14 vacation days

Tags: sql

I want a query that checks if a `employee` has more than 14 vacation days in a year. I want to make a `trigger` of it. It is important that this is 14 days in total. But the `employee` could have 4 days in one month and 10 days in another. He don't need to take the days in one go.

I have something like this (query) I'm using SQL Server

```
select employeeid
from time
where datediff(day, dateStart, dateEnd) >=1
and year(dateEnd) = 2018
and timecat= 'vacationdays'
group by employeeid
having count(*) >=13
```

I thought I could use a datediff and have this count like 13 times. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Some sample data would really help here.  Also, if you're using SQL Server, please add that tag to your question.  SQL is just a language, not a specific product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the date differences:

```
select employeeid, sum(datediff(day, dateStart, dateEnd) + 1) AS total
from time
where year(dateEnd) = 2018
and timecat= 'vacationdays'
group by employeeid
having SUM(datediff(day, dateStart, dateEnd) + 1) > 14
```

Consider the `+1` in `SUM` because `datediff` returns `1` for two dates like `'2018-11-16'` and `'2018-11-17'`, but if these are the `dateStart` and `dateEnd` you want the result to be `2`.  
There is still one problem remaining: what happens if `dateStart` and `dateEnd` are not dates of the same year!

Comment: Yes that problem I've also considered. But in my case that is not a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Count(*) just counts the number of rows.
This means if have an employee with two vacations one of 10 days and one of 4 days, (i assume that) this are only two rows in rows in your table and count star returns 2.

You can you the function SUM()

```
select employeeid, sum( datediff(day, dateStart, dateEnd) ) as sum
from time
where datediff(day, dateStart, dateEnd) >=1
and year(dateEnd) = 2018
and timecat= 'vacationdays'
group by employeeid
having sum >=13
```

I don't know the structure of your table, therefore I'm not quite sure if the query is correct, but here a further helpful links.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

[Getting the sum of a datediff result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508338/getting-the-sum-of-a-datediff-result)